# IIS7: URL Rewrite not working when debugging with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2008, iis-7, url-rewriting

I have set up some User Friendly URL rules in IIS7 using the URL Rewrite module. This works perfectly on IIS7.

However, when I try to debug the site, the webserver instance that Visual Studio creates doesn't seem to obey the rewrite rules.

For example,

```
http://localhost/friendly-url
```

works on IIS7, but

```
http://localhost:1800/friendly-url
```

returns a 404 error when debugging with Visual Studio 2008. Since the rewrite rules are present in web.config, I would have expected Visual Studio to obey them?

Wild Thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cassini doesn't do URL rewriting.  You might want to look at the recently announced [IIS Express](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/28/introducing-iis-express.aspx) version which will.

Quoting from the linked article:

> The downside with the ASP.NET
>   Developer Server, though, is that it
>   does not support a full set of
>   web-server features.  For example, it
>   doesn’t support SSL, URL Rewriting
>   Rules (like the SEO URL Rewrite Rules
>   I blogged about here), Custom Security
>   Settings, and other richer features
>   now offered with IIS 7.

Comment: Hi,

I have Windows 7 Home Premium, so I can't make Visual Studio use IIS7's web server - will I be able to do this with IIS express?

Comment: @Wild Thing -- you should be able to use IIS Express with Win7, Vista, and XP, if you want.

Comment: Indeed IIS Express will support all that, and its coming REALLY SOON!!!, so stay tuned

Comment: Hi, just a clarification - I can ALREADY use IIS7 with Win7. What I mean is, I can't use IIS7 as my debugging server in Visual Studio. Can this be done with IIS7 Express? If so, it should solve my problem!